# Query MongoDB no es como esperaba

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Tengo una colleccion que guarda datos de unos vehiculos de la siguiente forma:

```
{
  "vehicle_id": 50,
  "horometro": 100,
  "odometro": 23
},
{
  "vehicle_id": 30,
  "horometro": 220,
  "odometro": 50
},
{
  "vehicle_id": 50,
  "horometro": 300,
  "odometro": 56
}
```

Los vehiculos se repiten y el campo de horometro y odometro son acumuladores. Y lo que me interesa obtener es una agrupacion de los vehiculos que tenga el ultimo odometro y el ultimo horometro y adicional a esto dos campos de horometro_total y odometro_total que tenga el total del de la suma de todos los vehiculos del odometro y el horometro. Algo asi:

```
{
  "vehicle_id": 50,
  "horometro": 300,
  "odometro": 56,
  "horometro_total": 520,
  "odometro_total": 106
},
{
  "vehicle_id": 30,
  "horometro": 220,
  "odometro": 50,
  "horometro_total": 520,
  "odometro_total": 106
},
```

Habia tratatdo de hacerlo de esta forma:

```
const modelHistoryDetailedReport = function( id ){

    const projectOptions = {
        'ficha': 1,
        'odometro_veh': 1,
        'horometro_veh': 1,
        'horometer': { $round: [ "$horometer_sum", 4 ] },
        'odometer': { $round: [ "$odometer_sum", 4 ] },
    }
    
    this.objectQuery = [
        { $match:{ vehicle_id: id } },
        {
            $group : {
                _id: "$ficha",
                horometer_sum: { '$sum': '$horometro_veh' },
                odometer_sum: { '$sum': '$odometro_veh' },
            }
        },
        { $project: projectOptions },
        
    ];
}
```

Pero soy novato en MongoDB por tanto no ha quedado bien.

Comment: Hola, podrías aclarar mas tu pregunta? primero en `mongoDB` no existen tablas, sería mas útil que pusieras ejemplos de como son los documentos dentro de las colecciones, si quiera con 2 documentos distintos y también poner un ejemplo del documento que esperas obtener. En las imágenes que pusiste, para mi no es muy claro esos valores de donde salen (no les encuentro ninguna relación). Y en el código que pusiste, también usas un `$this.filter` que no sabemos que hace y unos campos que tampoco pusiste en ninguna parte de la descripción. pon en la pregunta lo necesario y quita lo que no sea.

Comment: @Pipe, gracias por la aclaración. Ya hice la modificación.

Comment: Solo una pregunta, porque necesitas el `horometer_sum` y el `odometer_sum` en cada documento? no podrías simplemente calcular esos valores en otra consulta? o obligatoriamente, si la consulta te devuelve 100 resultados, necesitas esos valores repetidos en cada uno de esos documentos?

Comment: @Pipe realmente no tiene porque ser todo el la misma consulta, lo plantee asi solo por simplicidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo sugeriría hacer 2 consultas, (pues no me parece útil repetir un dato en cada uno de los documentos), así:

Con esta consulta sacas el mayor de cada vehiculo ([MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PxvK1yXJIzy)):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$vehicle_id",
      "horometro": {
        "$max": "$horometro"
      },
      "odometro": {
        "$max": "$odometro"
      }
    }
  }
])

//Retorna:
[
  {
    "_id": 30,
    "horometro": 220,
    "odometro": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": 50,
    "horometro": 300,
    "odometro": 56
  }
]
```

Y con esta obtendrías las sumatoria del horometro y odometro, para obtener los totales ([MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AdkdNHGAM7h)):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$vehicle_id",
      "horometro": {
        "$max": "$horometro"
      },
      "odometro": {
        "$max": "$odometro"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      odometro_sum: {
        $sum: "$odometro"
      },
      horometro_sum: {
        $sum: "$horometro"
      }
    }
  }
])

//Retorna:
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "horometro_sum": 520,
    "odometro_sum": 106
  }
]
```